# How to integrate 'append' and 'print' Python code in a line?

Tags: python, append

python newbie here. I wonder if I can write the `append` and `print` syntax in a line instead of two. I tried twice but failed, as shown below:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
y = 7
a.append(y)
print(a) #correct [1, 2, 3, 4, 7]
```

(1)

```
print(a.append(y)) #retuns None
```

(2)

```
print(a = a.append(y)) #returns 'a' is an invalid keyword argument for print()
```

A more important question is: May I know the reason of failure? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: No, you can't do this. Nor do I see the reason for it.

Comment: Pro tip: there’s no shortage of lines. Printing and appending are two different things, and should be written on separate lines to make that apparent when reading the code. Python heavily skews towards this view anyway.

Comment: `.append` modifies the list in place and returns `None` so there is nothing to print.

Comment: Why is everyone suddenly trying to one-line python code, try https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ for that, not SO.

Comment: Got it. I'm not a one-line enthusiast, but feel strange why it simply does not work. Clarity prevails, of course.

Comment: Python's lists are mutable, so methods on them actually change them. In a language where the data structures are immutable, an operation like appending would return a new list.

Answer (score 3):

`.append()` returns `None`, so that's what `print()` is printing in attempt #1.

In attempt #2, you can't perform an assignment quite like that. If you have Python 3.8 or later, you can use the assignment expression operator `:=` like this:

```
print(a := a.append(y))
```

but not only will that still not print `a`, it replaces `a` with the `None` that `.append()` returns.

As for how to add to `a` and print `a` at the same time, since `.append()` returns `None`, this construct will work:

```
print(a.append(y) or a)
```

Since the left side of the `or` will evaluate to `None`, the value of the expression will be the right side, `a`.

But I wouldn't do that. It's unnecessary and confusing. Clever one-liners are no substitute for readable code.

Comment: I was about to suggest something silly with a tuple, but I like this better.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can't do this using append, but try this:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
y = 7
print([*a,y])
```

Comment: Does not change `a`.